# Permanently Enable Wi-Fi On a Smartwatch

Tags: wi-fi, adb, settings

I bought a children android smartwatch, MyKi Junior, running Android 4.2, which is intended for the specific purposes of parenting. I found out that it has a wifi chip that is usually used for detection of the watches' position (for safe zone). I was able to access the settings and connect to ADB. Every time I'm enabling the wifi, it gets automatically disabled. As a result, I only see a glimpse of the available networks. I surmised that there is an internal application that automatically turns off the wifi but I cannot figure out which of the many it is.

My question is if there is an ADB command that can enable the wifi permanently or any other way to enable wifi and bypass the automatic disable.

Comment: As you don't even tell use the exact device model name of the watch I doubt that anybody will be able to help you.

Comment: Good point. I will add this info.